# How to ensure that words in a Google Documents will be replaced corectly using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

Let's say I have this text in a Google Document: *My foo is not a bar is a foobar*. I want to replace all the foo, bar, and foobar text in that document using Google Apps Script. For that I am using a simple *for-in loop*:

```
const replaceWords = () =>{
  for (let key in mark){
    body.replaceText(key,marks[key])
  }
}
```

where marks are this object:

```
const marks = {
  "foo": "x",
  "bar": "y",
  "foobar": "z"
}
```

How can I be sure that words like *foobar* won't be replaced as *xy* instead of *z*? From what I understand, setting the keys with "\b" boundary matcher, like here `\\bfoo\\b`, should ensure that, but it made it worse

Comment: I don't know google apps script, but from regex standpoint, your replacement should work. What do you mean by "it made it worse"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised script**

```
function replaceMarks() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var body = doc.getBody()

  const marks = {
  "foo": "x",
  "bar": "y",
  "foobar": "z"
  }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(marks)) {
    body.replaceText('\\b'+key+'\\b',value)
  }
}
```

The [syntax](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) for "replaceText" is `replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)`. `searchPattern` "is passed as a string, not a JavaScript regular expression object. Because of this you'll need to escape any backslashes in the pattern."

The searchPattern becomes `'\\b'+key+'\\b'`

- `\b` is a word boundary; so it ensures *whole* words.
- These are escaped with a backslash.
- the variable is inserted between the escaped regex.
- the whole thing is passed as a string.

---

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: After]