# Autofill Google Docs from Spreadhseet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I used the below code to autofill a standard Google Doc from a spreadsheet and it is only half working. It runs fine, creating a new google doc from the template I created, naming this correctly and inserting the link into the original spreadsheet for easy reference. The issue is that it doesn't seem to be filling in any of the data I have asked it to fill in (just retains the template info). I've checked my headings and column numbers and it all seems correct...

The code is:

```
function onOpen() {
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
menu.addToUi();
}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {

const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1ONJpemIqAwfTuEnRhkeoVnqVnfnWVexG_RnmzsP96FQ');
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('19OwE5z9AnJ0nzEvU-lJ0tNTw3yJM2BHH')
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form responses 1')
const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

rows.forEach(function(row, index){
if (index === 0) return;
if (row[6]) return;
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[0]} Student Details` , destinationFolder)
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
const body = doc.getBody();
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();

body.replaceText('{{What is your full name?}}', row[0]);
body.replaceText('{{What are your personal pronouns?}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{What is your personal email address?}}', row[2]);
body.replaceText('{{What is your school student email?}}', row[3]);
body.replaceText('{{What is your mobile phone number?}}', row[4]);
body.replaceText('{{Do you have anything that you would like us or your tutor to know?}}', row[5]);

doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 7).setValue(url)

  })

}
```

The Google Doc template is filling into the following:

Student # details:

Student name: {{What is your full name?}} ({{What are your personal pronouns?}})

Student email 1: {{What is your personal email address?}}

Student email 2: {{What is your school student email?}}

Student phone number: {{What is your mobile phone number?}}

Subject: FILL

Comments/requests from your student: {{Do you have anything that you would like us or your tutor to know?}}

The spreadsheet it is collecting the data from has the following column headings (A-G):

A:What is your full name?

B:What are your personal pronouns?

C:What is your personal email address?

D:What is your school student email?

E:What is your mobile phone number?

F:Do you have anything that you would like us or your tutor to know?

G:Document Link

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: `?` is regarded as a "special character" in Regex. The specific names of the placeholders in Word do NOT have to align to the questions in Sheets. So, try editing your Google Doc Template (and the script, of course) to remove the "question marks". You could also try and simply them them. e.g. "{{What is your full name?}}" => "{{Full Name}}", etc

Comment: OK. I'm going to add that comment as an answer so that future users might get some value from this Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

`?` is regarded as a "special character" in Regex.

One alternative is to `escape` the special character by doing something along the lines mentioned in [How to ensure that words in a Google Documents will be replaced correctly using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75915751/1330560). But that requires the user to delve into regex, which is not everybody's *thing*.

There *is* an easier solution:

- The specific names of the placeholders in Word do NOT have to align to the questions in Sheets.
- Try editing your Google Doc Template (and the script, of course) to remove the "question marks".
- You could also try and simplify them. e.g. "{{What is your full name?}}" => "{{Full Name}}", etc